# how to get a full size height of customscrollview widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, height, customscrollview

I want to get the whole height of CustomScrollView widget. So I made a below code but it's not working.

```
@override
void initState(){
 super.initState();
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getSizeAndPosition());
}

getSizeAndPosition() {
    RenderBox _customScrollBox =
        _customScrollKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    _customScrollSize = _customScrollBox.size;
    _customScrollPosition = _customScrollBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print(_customScrollSize.height);
    setState(() {});
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _customScrollKey,
      appBar: _appbar(),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            _titleSection(),
            _thumnail(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The height obtained by this code does not take into account the height of the list in the customScrollview. I mean, `_customScrollSize.height` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` are the same.

[I want this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx5iM.png)

```
_controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (_controller.offset < 0) {
          scrollHeight = 0;
        } else {
          scrollHeight = _controller.offset;
        }
      });
    });


 Container(
   width: size.width * (scrollHeight / _customScrollSize.height),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   border: Border(
           bottom: BorderSide(
           width: 1)),
```

With the above code, '_customScrollSize.height' does not reflect the overall height and therefore the function is not implemented properly. Is there any good way to use it in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

**[CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)**

A ScrollView that creates custom scroll effects using slivers.

A [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) lets you supply slivers directly to create various scrolling effects, such as lists, grids, and expanding headers. For example, to create a scroll view that contains an expanding app bar followed by a list and a grid, use a list of three slivers: `SliverAppBar`, `SliverList`, and `SliverGrid`.

In your case do remove the appBar and use a sliverAppBar withing the custome scrollview , and you can use [sliverfillRemaining](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html) widget for your other children

example

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    const SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 250.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
    ),
SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            _titleSection(),
            _thumnail(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])),
...
```

Comment: Thanks for `SliverFillRemaining`. Too bad it doesn't appear in the example, however